# Call controller Action with empty/null strings as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an action in my controller which takes 2-3 parameter like as shown below.

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string str1, string str2, string str3)
{
     // code here 
}
```

This action is called with some valid values as parameters and results are displayed in the view. Now I want to call the same action again and want to pass empty/null string values as parameter. But when I call the action like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click", "MyAction", "MyController")
```

The route template is as follows:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{str1}/{str2}/{str3}",
        new {controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction", str1 = UrlParameter.Optional, str2 = UrlParameter.Optional, str3 = UrlParameter.Optional}
    );
}
```

I got the same values as the parameter, how I can call the action with empty/null values as paramter?

Comment: What do you mean by " same values as the parameter"? `@Html.ActionLink("Click", "MyAction", "MyController")` should call the action method with null values for parameters

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath I mean I get the same values as the parameter when this action was called for the first time, when the action is called again, I I get the same values again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click", "MyAction", "MyController", new { str1 = "", str2 = "" , str3 = "" })
```

Comment: I have used as per your suggestions, but I am still getting values :(

Comment: What is the value you are getting in for example `str1` ?

Comment: same value as calling the action method for the first time

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache ? or use another browser .

Answer (score 0):

You can use C# optional parameter here

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string str1="", string str2="", string str3=null)
{
     // code here 
}
```

```
@Html.ActionLink("link", "About", "Home")

public ActionResult MyAction(string str1="", string str2="", string str3=null)
{
    //values
     str1=="";
     str2=="";
     str3==null;
}
```

```
@Html.ActionLink("link", "About", "Home", new { str1="a", str2="b", str3="c" })

public ActionResult MyAction(string str1="", string str2="", string str3=null)
{
    //values
     str1=="a";
     str2=="b";
     str3=="c";
}
```

Comment: I have used as per your suggestions, but I am still getting values :(